# Move buttons on a page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My button can move, but weirdly, I can't figure out if it's something wrong with the offset.

I want my buttons to move with my mouse cursor, but now it's moving not in a way that I want and sometimes it disappears.

Also, the new buttons created are overlapping, I don't know how to solve that and have a nicer look.

```js
var coorA;
var coorB;
var btn = null;

function mousedown() {
    if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
        btn = event.target;
        coorA = btn.offsetTop;
        coorB = btn.offsetLeft;
    }
}

function mouseup() {
    btn = null;
}

function mousemove() {
    if (btn !== null) {
        btn.style.top = (event.clientY - coorA) + "px";
        btn.style.left = (event.clientX - coorB) + "px";
    }
}

function createButton() {
    var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var msg = document.getElementById("word").value;
    if (msg.length > 0) {
        var t = document.createTextNode(msg);
        button.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(button);
    }
    document.getElementById("word").value = "";
}
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}
#word {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

#add {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Poetry-yuc217</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form>
                <input id = "word" type = "text" name = "word">
                <input id = "add" type = "button" value = "Add Word" onclick = "createButton()">
                <br>
                
            </form>
            <button type="button" >this</button>
               

        </div>


        
   

enter code here
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your question in the comments:

> Thanks so much! I am still little confused about what "event" actually
>   refers to. From what I learned, event is all the actions on the page.
>   And that is not so clear...

In your code you have referenced the `event` object but haven't passed it as an argument. I believe you confusion may stem from this. Well, I was curios myself, and oh boy, down the rabbit hole I went...

I'll try to be as simple & general as I can, as I myself have yet completely wrapped my understanding of this.

OK, so there are different types of events in the browser. You probably know some of the standard ones such as "click, "onload", "keydown" etc. If you wish your code to do something when such an event occurs, you'll choose a DOM element such as `<button>`, `<div>` etc (**generally speaking**, because there are also non-DOM related events, you can read all about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events). You then attach this element to a function that will be invoked when the said event is triggered.

There are different ways of attaching such a function (which BTW is also called the *event handler* or *event listener*). When attaching the event handler, something called the *EventListener interface* is being implemented. A function that was triggered through an event will get an argument, a Event object, courtesy of the interface (https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20131105/#glossary-event-handler).

BUT!!! If you attach an event using the inline method i.e `<a onclick="myFunc();" />` your function will receive the argument (the `event`) only if "event" is written inside the function, i.e `<a onclick="myFunc(event);" />`.

You can observe this odd behavior and the different types of event attaching in this JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/duwed8kg/

I am uncertain as to why this happens, but it's a damn good subject for new question.

P.S, Regarding your code and the main question (for which I only provided the code, sans an explanation) -- It is problematic in different ways (the inline event attaching, element selection via tag names for ex), I focused on solving your problem with minimal changes to your code/style, but please be aware of it.

```js
var coorA;
var coorB;
var btn = null;
var lastMouseX;
var lastMouseY;

function mousedown() {
    if (event.target.className.indexOf("listButton") > -1) {
        btn = event.target;
        if(btn.style.top === "" || btn.style.left === "") {
          btn.style.position = "absolute";
          btn.style.top = btn.offsetTop + "px";
          btn.style.left = btn.offsetLeft + "px";
        }
        coorA = btn.offsetTop;
        coorB = btn.offsetLeft;
    }
}

function mouseup() {
    btn = null;
}

function mousemove() {
    if (btn !== null) {
        btn.style.top = parseInt(btn.style.top) + (event.clientY - lastMouseY) + "px";
        btn.style.left = parseInt(btn.style.left) + (event.clientX - lastMouseX) + "px";
    }
    lastMouseX = event.clientX;
    lastMouseY = event.clientY;
}

function createButton() {
    var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var msg = document.getElementById("word").value;
    if (msg.length > 0) {
        var t = document.createTextNode(msg);
        button.appendChild(t);
        button.classList.add("listButton");
        document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].appendChild(button);
    }
    document.getElementById("word").value = "";
}
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", createButton);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}

.container {
  position:relative;
  height:1000px;
}

#word {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

button {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.listButton {
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
}
#add {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Poetry-yuc217</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form>
                <input id = "word" type = "text" name = "word">
                <input id = "add" type = "button" value = "Add Word">
                <br>
                
            </form>
            <button type="button" class="listButton">this</button>
               

        </div>


        
   

enter code here
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I am still little confused about what "event" actually refers to. From what I learned, event is all the actions on the page. And that is not so clear...

Comment: You're welcome! I tried to answer you here but was limited by the characters, so I edited it into the main answer above.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the over-lap create an un-ordered list and then append`<li><button type="button" >fieldValue</button></li>`to the un-ordered list.

```
<ul id="buttonList">
     <li><button type="button" >this</button></li>
     <li><button type="button" >that</button></li>
     <li><button type="button" >the other</button></li>
</ul>
```

As for the moving button I wasn't able to replicate, they had some lag but they were moving fine for me, maybe if you need additional assistance you can prepare a demo using jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But after I changed it to list, buttons are still on top of each other. not completely overlapped though.

Comment: use css to style the list, add padding etc. you may also want to remove the black disc though you cant see them with your background color.