# Drag and drop a button on page in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create buttons that can be moved throughout the page but everything I have tried isn't working for me. 
Even running the example on: [Move buttons on a page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210286/move-buttons-on-a-page-using-javascript)
does not work.

So far my javascript file is only able to create the buttons that I need:

```
function add(text) {
console.log("New button with text: "+ text);
var word = document.createElement("button");
word.type = "button";
word.id = "magnet";
word.draggable = true;
word.value = text;
word.onclick = "dragstart(event);";
var fridge = document.getElementById("poem");
//fridge.appendChild(word);
word.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
fridge.appendChild(word);

$("#addbutton").val(""); }
```

Can someone explain how to move a button using clientX and clientY?

This is my html file...

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="poetry.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="addbutton">
    <button type="button" onclick="add(addbutton.value);">Add Word</button>
    <div id="poem"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not use a JQuery for this, simple drag and drop...

Comment: @TGarrett I have to use clientX and clientY for the assignment. Also mouseup, mousedown and mousemove